# Sobolev spaces are isomorphic to $L^2$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I understand that the Sobolev space $H^{s}:=\left\{u\in L^2:=L^2(\mathbb{R}^n): \int_{\mathbb{R} ^n} |(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty\right\}$ is isomorphic to $L^2$ for any $s\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Question 1**. This is right?
The isomorphism is $T:L^2\to H^{s}$ given by $Tu(\xi)=(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)$.

The argument to verify the surjectivity of the map $T$ consists in using the fact that $\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}}$ is bounded. Indeed, if $v\in H^{s}$, then $Tu=v $ with $\widehat{u}=\frac{1}{(1 +|\xi|^2)^{s/2}}v$. As $v\in L^2$ by definition of the space $H^{s}$ and $\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}}$ is bounded, then $\widehat{u}$ is in $L^2$, and by Plancherel's theorem, $u$ is in $L^2$.Therefore, $T$ is surjective.

**Question 2**. If a weighted space is defined, denoted and defined by $H^{s}(f):=\left\{u\in L^2: \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |(1+f(\xi))^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty\right\}$.

Would this space also be isomorphic to $L^2$ if $f$  is assumed to be a function such that $\frac{1}{1+f(\xi )^{s/2}}$ is bounded?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't worked with Sobolev spaces,  but you could always use the theorem that all Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to $l^2$ space of the cardinality of their Hilbert Dimension.  Do you know the Hilbert dimensions of your space?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am studying these issues and your comment raised the following new questions.
 By Proposition 5.3.4 in a course in abstract analysis by Conway, all Hilbert spaces are isomorphic.
Question 3. $H^{s}$ is separable? right?
Question 4. $H^{s}(f)$ is Hilbert and separable?

Comment: It's not all Hilbert spaces are isomorphic,  it's all Hilbert spaces of the same Hilbert dimension are isomorphic.  In particular,  if they are both separable, then they are the same Hilbert dimension.  Are these?  I'm not sure, been too long since I've done functional analysis